# How to make the cross marker always visible (Google Map V3)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, icons, visible

I want this small "X" (cross icon) in google maps api v3 set always visible, that means also when I am not dragging the icon.

Now the cross icons shows only when I am dragging the icon only.

Comment: show some code first

Comment: marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude),
     draggable: markerDraggable,
     icon: image
    });

Comment: your requirement is very unclear please provide jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
     cursor : 'crosshair'
   });
});
```

or the cursor name  you prefer